# React Native Expo BackHandler functionality

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

Can add `backhandler` to only one screen?

I use bottom tab and stack navigation

```
tab : {
 screen : stack A,
 screen : stack B,
}

stack A : {
 screen : screen A1,
 screen : screen A2,
 screen : screen A3
}
stack B : {
 screen : screen B1,
 screen : screen B2
}
```

I can navigate from screen B1 to screen A2 and screen A1 to A2.

If i navigate from screen B1 to A2 and pressed back in A2, Screen B1 should focus,
and same as Screen A1 to A2.

I tried added back handler in screen A2, and i pass flag from B1 and A1 to navigate to respective screen.

The problem is when i'm in screen A3 and press back, can't redirect to screen A2.

`I need to handle back button only on screen A2.`

Comment: Hardware back button in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BackHandler` using `react-navigation` like

Create `BackHandler.js` in components

```
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

function ProfileScreen({ onBackPress }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    React.useCallback(() => {
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", onBackPress);
    }, []),
  }, []);
}
```

Usage like

```
import BackHandler from "./components";

renderBackHandler = () => {
      return (
        <BackHandler
          onBackPress={() => {
            this.handleBackPress();
            return false;
          }}
        />
      );
    } 

render(){
  // ...

  {this.renderBackHandler()}

  // ...
}
```

Comment: im using react-navigation version < 5, so i don't have useFocusEffect, is there any other solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a React hook or just a functional component that you can call and you can have navigation include in the component. you can check the navigation state and just exit the app if you are not in the corresponding navigation state(view).

```
import {  BackHandler, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'


export const HardwareBackPress = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const backAction = () => {
    if (navigation.getState().routes[loc.routes.length - 1].name != 'DashBoard'){

    }else{
      Alert.alert('기다리다!', '정말 나가시겠습니까?', [
        {
          text: '취소',
          onPress: () => null,
          style: '취소',
        },
        { text: '예', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
      ]);
      return true;
    }
  };

  function backPressAssign() {
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }

  return {
    backPressAssign,
  }
}
```